# How many distinct samples of size n are there when we sample from a population of size N with replacement?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

If the population is size N, and the sample size is n, how can I generalize this case:
I want to find the number of distinct samples of size n that can be selected from the population, WITH replacement.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unordered sampling with replacement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922446/unordered-sampling-with-replacement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be found is the cardinality of the set of tuples $(n_1,\dots,n_N)$ where the $n_i$ are nonnegative integers that satisfy: $$n_1+\cdots+n_N=n$$

With [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find that this cardinality equals:$$\binom{n+N-1}{N-1}$$

Comment: Aren't tuples order-preserving meaning $(1,2)$ is not the same as $(2,1)$, and if so then then aren't you counting some samples multiple times?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSalman Indeed tuples are order-preserving. If e.g. we have populatione $(a,b)$ then $(1,2)$ stands for the sample of once $a$ and twice $b$ while $(2,1)$ stands for the sample of twice $a$ and once $b$. Here $a$ and $b$ are distinguishable (e.g. persons).

Comment: I don't understand this condition n1+⋯+nN=n. 
if n is just the sample size in question, why isn't the solution just N^n? 

i.e. N ways to choose each element in the sample, taken over a sample of size n. N ways to choose the first element * N ways to choose the second * ... * N ways the choose the nth element...

Comment: further, does this method double count the tuple (1,1), say?

Comment: Suppose $N=3$ in the sense that the population has $3$ distinguishable objects A,B,C. If e.g. $n=2$ then what samples are possible with replacement? $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ I would say where the first coördinate stands for the number of times object A is chosen, the second for the number of times object B is chosen and the third for the number of times object C is chosen. So there are $6$. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @drhab thank you